# Descendant of the Prophet and specificities to have in life

Tags: children, polygamy, sayyid

Salam 'Alaykoum,

I am potentially Sayyid (Descendant of the Prophet), and I would like to know if there are any specific things to apply or recommendations for Sayyid people.

I am thinking of having children (or many children), being polygamous, being even more careful with language etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah sayyed, the brahmins of Islam.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing. Abu Talib uncle of Prophet Muhammad(ﷺ) who took care of him was sayyid is in hellfire. The chances of you being sayyid is very remote. This title is claimed by many of them today. Most likely your forefathers would have added the title to of their children and it carries on. Your title will not decide if you enter paradise or hellfire. Allah says in Surah Hujurat verse 13 that the most honourable in the sight of Allah is the person of Taqwa(Piety, God fearing, God consciousness).

> O humanity! Indeed, We created you from a male and a female, and made
> you into peoples and tribes so that you may ˹get to˺ know one another.
> Surely the most noble of you in the sight of Allah is the most
> righteous among you. Allah is truly All-Knowing, All-Aware.